# Check if key-value pair from one array exists in another – with different key name (php)

Tags: php, arrays

I am editing this question as my arrays should in fact have been multidemensional arrays.

I wish to iterate though *$array_food*. I would like to print the the value of *snack->'banana'* but only if *food->'banana'* exists in a separate array, *$array_healthyfood*.

```
$array_food = array (
[0] => Array
    (
    snack  => 'banana',
    breakfast => 'cereal',
    drink => 'water'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
    snack  => 'apple',
    breakfast => 'eggs',
    drink => 'juice'
    )
)

$array_healthyfood = array (
[0] => Array
    (
    food  => 'banana',
    breakfast => 'cereal',
    drink => 'water'
    )

[1] => Array
    (
    food  => 'apple',
    breakfast => 'eggs',
    drink => 'juice'
    )
)
```

I have tried the following:

```
<?php foreach ($array_food as $foodelement):
if (in_array($foodelement->snack->$fruit, $array_healthyfood)) {
echo $foodelement->snack->$fruit;
}
endforeach; ?>
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: FYI: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Comment: Please show us the contents of both your arrays. `var_dump($arrayfood)` and `var_dump($array_healthyfood)`. It's very unclear and confusing what your actual data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

How to figure out whether one particular item exists in the healthy foods array:

```
array_reduce($healthyFood, function ($exists, array $hf) {
    return $exists || $hf['food'] == 'Banana';
})
```

(This can be done with a normal loop, or a custom function, or many other ways. I've chosen a functional array reduction here.)

How to do this for each item in an array:

```
foreach ($foods as $food) {
    $exists = array_reduce($healthyFood, function ($exists, array $hf) use ($food) {
        return $exists || $hf['food'] == $food['snack'];
    });
    if ($exists) ..
}
```

How to filter the food array by healthy foods:

```
$foods = array_filter($foods, function (array $food) use ($healthyFood) {
    return array_reduce($healthyFood, function ($exists, array $hf) use ($food) {
        return $exists || $hf['food'] == $food['snack'];
    });
});
```

How to do this more efficiently than continuously looping the healthy foods array:

```
$healthyFoods = array_map(function (array $hf) { return $hf['food']; }, $healthyFoods);

foreach ($foods as $food) {
    if (in_array($food['snack'], $healthyFoods)) ...
}
```

Comment: There could be more than one value for food in $array_healthyfood. I have amended the question.

Comment: No, that is *not possible*. You cannot have the same key twice in your array.

Comment: In my example data $array_healthy food is a multidimensional array. Will amend.

Comment: Hi deceze. Still having a bit of trouble here. Can you confirm that your $foods is my $array_food, your $healthyFood is my $array_healthyFoods and that $hf and $exists are new variables for which I can use any name?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes and yes.

Answer (score -1):

OK, I haven't tested this, just kind of wrote it out. It may need some tweaking. I'm assuming you've tested whether you're actually getting the $fruit var back ok.

Revised version based on array map

```
<?php
$flipped_healthyfood = array_flip($array_healthyfood);
foreach($arrayfood as $key => $food){

    if( isset($flipped_healthyfood[$food]) ){
        echo $food; 
    }
}
?>
```